# 2 folders added to PATH contain different files with the same name

Tags: shell, path

I would like to know how to run a file in a case like this example:

I have two files in the paths:

```
/home/example/folder1/filewithname.sh
/home/example/folder2/filewithname.sh
```

I have both `folders` added to PATH, how can I specify which `filewithname.sh` I'm talking about?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The directories listed in the `PATH` variable will be searched *in the order in which they are listed*. When the given command is found, the search ends.

This means that if you added the two directories in the order that you show (`folder1` before `folder2`), then the command from `folder1` will be used if you just say `filewithname.sh` on the command line.  The `folder1` variant of the command effectively *shadows* the variant in `folder2`.

If you want the other variant of command, you will have to access it using its path, i.e. as `/home/example/folder2/filewithname.sh`, or via some equivalent pathname.

You may also create aliases for each of the commands so that you don't have to think about what order the directories are listed in `$PATH`.  For example,

```bsh
alias c1=/home/example/folder1/filewithname.sh
alias c2=/home/example/folder2/filewithname.sh
```

This would allow you to use `c1` and `c2` to execute the two scripts.

You could put these alias definitions in your shell's initialization file (e.g. in `~/.bashrc` if you're using `bash`, or in `${ZDOTDIR:-$HOME}/.zshrc` if you're using `zsh`).

Comment: Thanks! I ended up using a variable instead of PATH, but this is certainly useful information :)

Answer (score 1):

You can run the files individually based on their full path:

```
$ /home/example/folder1/filewithname.sh
$ /home/example/folder2/filewithname.sh
```

Or you can change to the directory of the individual files, and run the files based on their relative path. For example:

```
cd /home/example/folder1
~/example/folder1$ ./filewithname.sh

cd /home/example/folder2
~/example/folder2$ ./filewithname.sh
```

To run the files in this way, the execute bit has to be set on the files.

Comment: They seem like good options too! :) I actually kind of used this since I ended up using a variable, which at the end is like using the common full path + individual additions.