# Which binary is used (per specification) if there are multiple ones with the same name at different locations in PATH?

Tags: environment-variables, path

If two different directories in the PATH environment variable both contain a binary with the same name (but slightly different behavior), are there specifications/guarantees on which one will be used?

On my machine (macOS Monterey, Darwin 21.2.0) I observed (via `which <binary name>`) that the binary is chosen from the first directory found in PATH (reading its content left to right). But is this standard behavior across all Linux/UNIX-ish OSes? i.e. is there some standard that enforces it (e.g. POSIX)?

**Extra context (for the curious ones)**:
I'm writing a project that has a script that downloads a custom version of a standard binary in a project-specific folder and then invokes another script that MUST use the custom binary rather than the regular one. I'm adding the folder with the custom binary to PATH before invoking the second script. Given what I've observed on how PATH is searched in case of collisions, I'm setting PATH as `PATH=<my-custom-folder>:$PATH` rather than `PATH=$PATH:<my-custom-folder>`. But this project has multiple collaborators, and I want to make sure that we all run the same binary. If different OSes searched PATH in ways different than mine, things would break.

Comment: AFAIK, most shells invoke the first matching binary they find, without searching the remaining directories in `$PATH`.

Comment: It's not specifically a shell thing, @SottoVoce; it's defined and built in to the `exec(3)` family of library calls

Comment: @ChrisDavies  If I read the man page correctly, Bash may circumvent the `exec` call. If the standard command has already been called by this shell, the absolute path of the command will have been hashed, and Bash will pass this to `exec(3)`, which will not even search the modified `PATH`. The hash needs to be explicitly revoked with `hash -r` or `hash -d name`.

Comment: Fair point, @Paul_Pedant. I've amended my answer to provide a specific reference to shell execution w.r.t `$PATH`

Comment: It seems saver to actually find a unique name for that custom binary.

Comment: @FelixJN, yes. But I've also used this PATH search guarantee sometimes to override system applications. `rename` is one, for example. Either with newer versions that I can't get through the package manager, or on rare occasion by changing behaviours (providing extra options for things that I do regularly) with a simple shell script that then calls the real binary

Comment: Probably a duplicate of this: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/634069/2-folders-added-to-path-contain-different-files-with-the-same-name?rq=1

Comment: @Kusalananda certainly related, but I don't think it's a duplicate. This question (here) asked for detail of the specification (which I've assumed means POSIX); your suggestion asked how to call executables without needing to rely on the `PATH` directory ordering

Answer (score 4, accepted):

POSIX defines the library calls [`execlp(3)` and `execvp(3)`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/exec.html) as searching the environment variable `PATH` for the location of the specified executable. (Unless the executable has a relative or absolute path specified for its name, such as `/bin/ls` or `./a.out`, that is.)

The [POSIX definition of `PATH`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html#tag_08_03) is such that,

> This variable shall represent the sequence of path prefixes that certain functions and utilities apply in searching for an executable file known only by a filename. The prefixes shall be separated by a  ( ':' ). […] *The list shall be searched from beginning to end*, applying the filename to each prefix, until an executable file with the specified name and appropriate execution permissions is found.

A POSIX shell [must also follow](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_09_01_01) (part 1e) this approach, even if it does not directly defer searching the `$PATH` to one of the `exec(3)` functions.

So to answer your question directly, if you have an unqualified command (such as `ls`), the first executable found in a directory specified in the list contained in `$PATH` will be used. Not necessarily a binary as scripts can also be executable. (If the command contains `/` in its pathname then it is used directly, with the current directory being the starting point for a relative pathname.)

Thinking more about your underlying requirement. Perhaps you should define your own environment variable (`MYAPP_DIR`, for example) that points to the directory holding your application's executables. You can then invoke the equivalent of `$MYAPP_DIR/myutility` rather than relying on the user's `$PATH` to be correct at all times.